# Calendar Class method in Java seems to be not giving correct result

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

Can someone please explain why is the behavior of the below piece of code not as expected.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfYears = 3;
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();//Today's date is December 28, 2023
        now.add(Calendar.YEAR, numberOfYears);// Adding 3 years to it
        Date date = now.getTime(); 
        String expectedExpiryDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, YYYY").format(date); //expected date should be December 28, 2026
        System.out.println(expectedExpiryDate + " expectedExpiryDate");// But we are getting output as December 28, 2027

    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcne0.png)

If we add 1 year to today's date then we do get expected result i.e  December 28, 2024. However, if we add 2 or 3 years to today's date it becomes December 28, 2026 and December 28, 2027 respectively

Comment: I just ran your code through a debugger. The issue is in the SimpleDateFormat. The `Date date = now.getTime();` is able to get the time correctly, but the formatting somehow pushes it a year forward. Also, please learn to use a debugger and use the more reliable `java.time` package

Comment: Don’t fiddle with format patterns yourself when you can avoid it. It’s error-prone, and in this case there is an easy, clear and safe alternative: `LocalDate .now() .plusYears(3) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(Locale.US))`. Just yielded `December 29, 2026`, three years from now.  In 19 out of 20 cases both you and your users will prefer Java’s built-in localized format for the user’s locale.

Comment: I upvoted this question despite the code example not being exactly minimal. It is short and reproducible (depending on locale). With the good first answer it may also be a fine original for duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().plusYears( 3 ).toString()
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

Stop using `Calendar`. That class is a legacy class, long ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, `Date`, `Timestamp`, etc.

Do not waste your time trying to understand these legacy date-time classes. They are terribly flawed, with bizarre features. They are entirely replaced by *java.time*, so move on. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community have.

### *java.time*

Capture the current date only, without time-of-day, and without time zone, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Determining the current date requires a time zone. If omitted the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied.

```java
ZoneId zoneTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate todayTokyo = LocalDate.now( zoneTokyo ) ;
```

[Add](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusYears(long)) three years.

```java
LocalDate threeYearsLater = todayTokyo.plusYears( 3 ) ;
```

To generate text is standard ISO 8601 format, call [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString()). To generate text in localized format, use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle)).

Be sure to specify your desired/expected [locale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html). Relying on the JVM’s current default locale can be dicey. And doing so implicitly (by omitting any mention of locale) leaves the user wondering if you are aware of how localization works.

```java
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
        DateTimeFormatter
                .ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.LONG )
                .withLocale ( locale );
String output = threeYearsLater.format ( f );
```

> output = December 30, 2026

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Nope, not a typo. There are *two* classes named `Date` in the legacy framework. That is but one of many poor choices made then.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Basil. I wanted the output in the format. "MMMM d, YYYY".
Example: December 28, 2026

I tried using the java.time packages class and methods

Comment: @Nagraj1990 Basil has already mentioned the answer to that. use the DateTimeFormatter, but specify the pattern you want

Comment: Yes, I did try it
String datePattern = "MMMM d, YYYY";
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);
System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(LocalDate.now().plusYears(2)));
But, this doesn't seem to give expected output. i.e December 28, 2025

This does give
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).format(LocalDate.now().plusYears(2));
But, the format is not as per my expectation.

Comment: Try `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.UK);` Works fine for me. Absolutely no need to use Joda or other 2rd party libraries.

Comment: @Nagraj1990 Generating text with *java.time* has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So I had intended for you to look that up with a search, and read the Javadoc to which I pointed you. But given the discussion in Comments, I went ahead and added some example code.

Answer (score 0):

I came across org.joda.time package and this seems to be providing the expected output.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime currentLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime expectedDate = currentLocalDateTime.plus(new Period().withYears(3));
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM d, YYYY");
    String dateString = formatter.print(expectedDate);
    System.out.println(dateString);

}
```

}